# mysql update query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this php file for store the logout time. Using insert query I store the login time first. Then I store the logout time using this logout script. The error I'm getting is the one I mentioned in my code which is `failed to insert logout time`. the `$lgotime` and `$lrec` are echoing correctly. Below is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$lgotime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$lrec = $_SESSION['lreclast'];

echo $lgotime;

echo "</br>";

echo $lrec;

mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login_record SET logoff_time='$lgotime' WHERE id = '$lrec'") or die("failed to insert logout time");

session_destroy();
header("Location:../login.php");
?>
```

the `$lrec` variable is coming from `mysql_insert_id()` from the script that has the insert query. Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: what.. you are trying to insert or update?

Comment: I'm trying to update.

Comment: hey where is the connection string here...

Answer (score 3):

if your mysql query dosent work you can change your code like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login_record SET logoff_time='".$lgotime."' WHERE id = '".$lrec."'") or die("failed to insert logout time");
```

it always works for me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your query is not sending the data, its sending strings

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login_record SET logoff_time='$lgotime' WHERE id = '$lrec'") or die("failed to insert logout time");
```

Should be,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login_record SET logoff_time='{$lgotime}' WHERE id = {$lrec}") or die("failed to insert logout time");
```

To be honest I would not suggest this either and would use parametrized queries instead.

Comment: you are in php , not java or javascript ; concat using dot

Comment: Even so, the ID is going to be an integer presumably so id='$lrec' will still be incorrect.

Comment: @DavidHirst: MySQL ignores quotes around numerics when being set to numeric fields.

Answer (score 1):

Please give it a try.
  You are not using `session_start()` on top of this page and change query as

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $lgotime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$lrec = $_SESSION['lreclast'];

echo $lgotime;

echo "</br>";

echo $lrec;

mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login_record SET logoff_time='".$lgotime."' WHERE id = '".$lrec."'") or die("failed to insert logout time");

session_destroy();
header("Location:../login.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the query into the below format and try,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login_record SET logoff_time='".$lgotime."' WHERE id = '".$lrec."'") or die("failed to insert logout time");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **remove single quotes** from the id in your query because it is **integer** not **String**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login_record SET logoff_time='$lgotime' WHERE id = $lrec") or die("failed to insert logout time");
```